# Interpretation of Tensor product splines with multiple terms and their standard errors

Tags: standard-error, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

I am trying to understand the tensor product splines such as

```
library(mgcv)
vis.gam(gam(data=airquality, Ozone~s(Day, Month)), se = -1)
vis.gam(gam(data=airquality, Ozone~s(Day, Month, Temp)), se = -1)
vis.gam(gam(data=airquality, Ozone~s(Temp, Day, Month, Wind)), se = -1)
```

where visualised with generalised additive model such that

[image]

[image]

[image]

and lastly one standard errors such that

[image]

**How to explain the tensor product splines? Why is the order important in forming the splines with `s(...,...,...,...)`?**

Comment: If I am right, it is only plotting how ozone varies across the first two parameters, i.e., in the first plot, it is ozone ~ s(day, month), the second plot is also the same even when you have entered three regressors, and third plot is ozone  ~ s(temp,day). Perhaps, temp is a categorical data which is why you are seeing three plots. The key idea is to create a grid mesh of temp vs day or day vs month and use splines to fit a curve.

Comment: @Maxtron it is visualising the partial effects conditional upon some value for the other covariates. The models are estimating different effects, but not because of order but due to the increasing complexity of the smooth fitted. If you include extra covariates in a regression model, the partial effects of the other terms will change and that's what is happening here. The last plot is showing the uncertainty in the surface with green being the lower and red the upper limit (IIRC this is 1SE but it may be 2SE). Temp is certainly a continuous variable.

Answer (score 3):

These are not tensor product splines. What you are fitting are 2d and 3d thin plate splines. These kinds of smooths are generally inappropriate for the models you fit here because they assume isotropy; that a unit change in one marginal covariate is the same as a unit change in the other marginal covariate and that therefore a single smoothness penalty is appropriate.

Tensor product splines are produced by the `te()` function (or `t2()` for a different parameterisation).

Apart from the first `vis.gam()` call, you are trying to visualise the partial effect of two covariates conditional upon the others (the other covariates are generally held at some typical value, such as their mean). In the same way that including or removing a term in a simple regression model changes the estimated effect (the partial effect) of a covariate in both models (unless the covariates are orthogonal), changing what terms are in the GAM causes changes in the estimated partial effects of those covariates.

This is compounded here because you are removing or including terms from a single high-dimensional smooth, and furthermore, you are not changing the order of the terms in the model independently of which terms are in the model.

Compare

```
library('mgcv')
data(airquality)

m1 <- gam(Ozone ~ s(Day, Month, Temp), data=airquality, method = 'REML')
m2 <- gam(Ozone ~ s(Month, Day, Temp), data=airquality, method = 'REML')

> printCoefmat(summary(m1)$s.table)
                     edf Ref.df      F   p-value    
s(Day,Month,Temp) 13.495 16.379 9.9337 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> printCoefmat(summary(m2)$s.table)
                     edf Ref.df      F   p-value    
s(Month,Day,Temp) 13.494 16.379 9.9338 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

There are some slight differences but fitted values and summaries compare to the the first few decimal places. These difference are likely due to the way the 3d thin plate spline basis is being set up — it is a low-rank thin plate spline.

If we switch to tensor product smooths then the two models are the same regardless of order (note I have to set `k` lower here as it applies to each marginal so we have `k^3` terms here prior to application of identifiability constraints).

```
m1 <- gam(Ozone ~ te(Day, Month, Temp, k=4), data=airquality, method = 'REML')
m2 <- gam(Ozone ~ te(Month, Day, Temp, k=4), data=airquality, method = 'REML')

> all.equal(fitted(m1), fitted(m2))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Do tensor product splines assume isotrophy?

Comment: @hhh no; tensor product smooths do not assume isotropy. They involve multiple smoothness penalties: one per marginal smooth in the case of `te()` terms and one per marginal smooth plus one per "interaction" for `t2()` terms. The extra smoothness penalties in `t2()` terms is due to the special way the penalties on the basis functions are constructed.